# How to translate language packs in SocialEngine

Tags: translation, socialengine

I know that SocialEngine stores language files as CSV files in `application/languages`. The common format in the CSV files is as follows:

```
"Source word"; "Translated word"
```

But, this sometimes gets very complicated, especially when special characters are used in some parts, e.g.:

```
"Total Credits : %s";"Total Credits : %s"
"_EMAIL_SITEGROUP_BADGEREQUEST_APPROVED_EMAIL_TITLE";"Group Badge Request Approved"
"Video conversion failed. Please try uploading %1$sagain%2$s.";"Video conversion failed. Please try uploading %1$sagain%2$s."
"{item:$subject} replied to a comment on {item:$owner}\'\'s page offer {item:$object:$title}: {body:$body}";"{item:$subject} replied to a comment on {item:$owner}\'\'s page offer {item:$object:$title}: {body:$body}"
"3%s Level Category:";"3%s Level Category:"
"I have read and agree to the <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=window.open('%s','mywindow','width=500,height=500')>terms of service</a>.";"I have read and agree to the <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick=window.open('%s','mywindow','width=500,height=500')>terms of service</a>."
```

Answer (score 0):

> %s
>   -this is variable, and this means vareables are few:
>   %1$, %2$s
>   and so on... any number in X:
>   %X$

This is the key (in your case):

> "Total Credits : %s"

This is delimeter:

> ;

and this is your translation:

> "Total Credits : %s"

Cheers;)

Answer (score -1):

Without worrying about any of that, you can use this plugin: [Language Translator / Multilingual Plugin](https://www.socialengineaddons.com/socialengine-language-translator-multilingual-plugin)

Comment: Sorry, but I do need to know how the language files work.